# Why SSD serial number is different on Windows and Linux?

Tags: ssd, smart, wmic, smartctl

On Windows, I use

```
wmic diskdrive get Name, Manufacturer, Model, InterfaceType, MediaType, SerialNumber
```

and get `044A_5000_B130_099F.` as the SerialNumber.

However, on Linux, I use

```
sudo smartctl -i /dev/nvme0
```

and get `SS0L25186X2RC11X12CZ` as the Serial Number.

Reinstalling system (and booting from a live cd) does not change both value. But what causes the difference? And which one is true?

Comment: I've recently run into this issue too. Seems like Windows mangles the serial number for some reason. The one you get in Linux is the real one.

Comment: The Windows one seems to be EUI64.